# how to move a paypal button on website page

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I am building a website using wordpress.org.  On a page, I have an image, underneath the image a one line description, and underneath that the paypal button that can be clicked to order the product.  I want to move the paypal button to the right of the image.  I have looked online and cannot find out how to do this.  I am using Theme 2013.  I have added a CSS plugin.  I'm not very knowledgeable about CSS, but I am learning.  I don't know if this software can do the trick.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this in your pages HTML code should work:

```
<div style="float:left;">
<img src="https://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/your-image.jpg" alt="" width="183" height="276" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-499" />
<span>Caption</span>
</div>

<div>
/* 
your PayPal Code Here
*/
</div>


<div style="clear:both;"></div>


<div style="display: inline-block;">
/* 
your images here
*/
</div>
```

There is a detailed explanation of these methods here:

http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

The first Div holds your Image and uses the float element aligned left, so that the DIV with the PayPal code, will display to the right of the 'Image Div'.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm almost there.  The paypal button and description are displaying to the right of each image as I wanted.  However, now my images are stair stepping down the page.  For example, if image #1 is in column 10, then below it image #2 is in column 20, and below that image #3 is in column 30.  What code am I missing?

Comment: Without seeing your current html code, I would suggest adding a 'clear div' between the Div that holds the Image / PayPal button and the other images, and/or wrapping your lower images in a div and setting that divs style to display as an inline block. Updating the answer above to include this.